# replace all dashes but dash in phrase

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace all of the dashes in a string with spaces unless the dash is in the phrase `"not-replace"`. So the entire string would be like

```
var str = "change-these-dashes-but-not-replace-that";
```

so I could end up with `"change these dashes but not-replace that"

But what I've come up with isn't not matching the dash that's in the phrase I don't want to replace it in. How can I modify this?:

```
.match(/-(^not-replace)/gi);
```

Comment: How about replacing all dashes first, then replacing `not replace` with `not-replace`

Comment: @elclanrs: `var str = "change-these-dashed-bot-not-replace-that not replace";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach ([`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) from ES5 may be replaced with [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) from jQuery if used):

```
str.split('not-replace').map(function(s) {
    return s.replace(/-/g, ' ');
}).join('not-replace');  // "change these dashes but not-replace that"
```

Or even a bit shorter and (potentially) faster solution:

```
str.replace(/-|not-replace/g, function(s) { return s === '-' ? ' ' : s; });
```

The last will work constantly in all browsers.

Comment: You can safely drop the parentheses: `/-|not-replace/`.

Comment: @thg435 Sure. I even don't know why I have added them. Maybe I was thinking about performance, however finally it doesn't make any sense, since there is no other matches. Thanks!

Comment: I like that last one. Cool idea. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

Modern Javascript now support lookbehind assertions so editing my old answer accordingly.

You may use this regex with a nested lookahead and lookbehind:

```
repl = str.replace(/-(?!(?<=\bnot-)replace\b)/g, ' ');
//=> change these dashes but not-replace that
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pgp4vm/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `-`: match a `-`
- `(?!`: Start negative lookahead

  - `(?<=\bnot-)`: Must be preceded by word `not-`
  - `replace\b`: Match word `replace`
- `)`: End negative lookahead

Comment: What about `not` look-behind?

Answer (score 2):

```
str.replace(/not-replace/, 'notXXXreplace').replace(/-/, ' ').replace(/notXXXreplace/, 'not-replace');
```

I.e. first protect `not-replace` by changing it to something unlikely that doesn't contain dashes. Then replace all the dashes, and put back `not-replace` where the unlikely strings are.